# SQL Query: Order by greatest of two columns

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I've tried about a dozen different methods to solve this issue, and everything I try is breaking my query... I have the following code that is used to generate a loop of threads on a message board:

```
SELECT MB_TOPICS.*, MAX(MB_REPLIES.TIMESTAMP) AS LATEST 
FROM MB_TOPICS
LEFT JOIN MB_REPLIES
ON MB_TOPICS.TOPIC_ID = MB_REPLIES.TOPIC_ID
WHERE MB_TOPICS.CATEGORY_ID='$CATEGORY'
GROUP BY MB_TOPICS.TOPIC_ID
ORDER BY MB_TOPICS.STICKY DESC, LATEST DESC, MB_TOPICS.TIMESTAMP DESC
LIMIT $start,$limit";
```

This is basically pulling all of the topics within the category, and then via a join it is also getting a timestamp of the most recent reply (if any) from the replies table.

On the sort, I want to keep the most recently active threads at the top... currently (after sticky Y/N) it's sorting by most recent reply and then by the timestamp when the thread was created... this is wrong because it means a new thread will appear after an old thread with replies.  I've tried things like

```
GREATEST(LATEST, MB_TOPICS.TIMESTAMP)
```

or using IIF statements, CASE statements within the ORDER BY, etc., but anything I do is just breaking the query so that no results appear.  I just want to make this so that whichever timestamp is most recent (last reply or topic creation), it sorts descending on that largest value.  I know this must be simple but it's killing me today.  Thank you!

Edit: If it's helpful information here... the 'LATEST' column will be null for threads that have no replies...

Comment: Add a column to the result using `GREATEST(LATEST, MB_TOPICS.TIMESTAMP) as sort_order` and then `ORDER BY sort_order`

Comment: So I just tried that, and when I load the page I get a blank loop, my edited query was: 
 "SELECT MB_TOPICS.*, MAX(MB_REPLIES.TIMESTAMP) AS 
        LATEST, GREATEST(LATEST, MB_TOPICS.TIMESTAMP) AS 
       SORT_ORDER
 FROM MB_TOPICS
 LEFT JOIN MB_REPLIES
 ON MB_TOPICS.TOPIC_ID = MB_REPLIES.TOPIC_ID
 WHERE MB_TOPICS.CATEGORY_ID='$CATEGORY'
 GROUP BY MB_TOPICS.TOPIC_ID
 ORDER BY MB_TOPICS.STICKY DESC, SORT_ORDER DESC
 LIMIT $start,$limit";

Comment: Do you always feel the need to SHOUT your SQL Queries

Comment: Did you try running it through phpMyAdmin or some similiar query testing tool

Comment: Lol, sorry. For some reason I've always done my queries in caps, not intending to shout my question :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've actually never used phpMyAdmin to test my queries before! So when I try that and I'm using your suggestions of calling GREATEST(LATEST, MB_TOPICS.TIMESTAMP) as a new column in my result, it  gives an error (#1054) calling 'LATEST' an unknown column in the field list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I finally got it.  I had to use the MAX() function again rather than the alias, and coalesce to deal with the null values, combined with RiggsFolly's suggestion of pulling it as a new column, resulted in this functioning query:

```
"SELECT MB_TOPICS.*, MAX(MB_REPLIES.TIMESTAMP) AS LATEST, 
        GREATEST(COALESCE(MAX(MB_REPLIES.TIMESTAMP),0), MB_TOPICS.TIMESTAMP) AS SORT_ORDER
FROM MB_TOPICS
    LEFT JOIN MB_REPLIES ON MB_TOPICS.TOPIC_ID = MB_REPLIES.TOPIC_ID
WHERE MB_TOPICS.CATEGORY_ID='$CATEGORY'
GROUP BY MB_TOPICS.TOPIC_ID
ORDER BY MB_TOPICS.STICKY DESC, SORT_ORDER DESC
LIMIT $start,$limit";
```

Thanks, I wouldn't have gotten there without the discussion here.

Comment: Plus 1 for bothering to post an answer rather than just disappearing with your solution